# Jest with tyescript in monorepo doesn't work with dependency out of the root folder

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, monorepo

I use Jest with Typescript. I want to create a monorepo.
My folders structure is:

```
fe
|-app1
|--.jest.config.ts
|--tsconfig.json
|-shared
|--dummyData.ts
```

I want a unit test from `app1` to access some data from `shared` folder.

`fe/app1/demo.spec.ts`:

```
import { someData } from '@shared/dummyData' //<--HERE: the alias is works, but jest can not understand "export" keyword

descrube('demo' () => {
  it('demo test', () => {
    expect(someData).toBe('DUMMY'));
  })
})
```

`fe/shared/dummyData.ts`:

```
export const someData = 'DUMMY';
```

The problem is that jest throws an error:

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token
{"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export const someData = 'DUMMY';
                                                                                        ^^^^^^
```

As I understand it cannot parse typescript or es6 modules that were produced by ts and babel.
The thing that it **works fine while `shared` folder is inside `app1`**, but once it's outside (and outside the root folder, i.g `'<rootDir>/../shared/$1'`) it start throwing that error.

---

Here is my configs:

I described alias in `fe/app1/tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext", 
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["app/src/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["shared/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

And in `fe/app1/.jest.config.ts`:

```
module.exports = {
...
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^@shared/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/../shared/$1',
  }
}
```

---

Some thoughts:

- As I understand I have to tell to jest to apply same parsers (babel, etc) for the code outside of the rootDir.
- I guess it's possible to create a `tsconfig` in the root folder(`fe`), but I want to launch unit tests from `fe/app1` folder...
- Maybe it's possible to configure the things with such properties as `projects`, `roots` and etc, but I'm out of luck so far.

Comment: How did you setup jest in your monorepo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution:

**For monorepo it is important to have babel config as a JS file**

So, simply rename `.babelrc` to `babel.config.js` (in the folder you called jest from, in my case it is `fe/app1`)

For more info you could check [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6053#issuecomment-383632515) (and maybe [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6229#issuecomment-392205646))